# Unable to save data to redis cloud using redis-om JsonModel from google colab

Tags: redis

I'm trying to save data to redis cloud using redis-om JsonModel from google colab as persistant Json files.

Using the following script I recieve this error :

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/redis/connection.py in connect(self)
    706         try:
--> 707             sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
    708                 lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/redis/retry.py in call_with_retry(self, do, fail)
     45             try:
---> 46                 return do()
     47             except self._supported_errors as error:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/redis/connection.py in <lambda>()
    707             sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
--> 708                 lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
    709             )

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/redis/connection.py in _connect(self)
   1005         if err is not None:
-> 1006             raise err
   1007         raise OSError("socket.getaddrinfo returned an empty list")

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/redis/connection.py in _connect(self)
    993                 # connect
--> 994                 sock.connect(socket_address)
    995 

OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-4ee06a3d036c> in <cell line: 24>()
     22 
     23 # Create an instance of the model class with some data
---> 24 person = Person(name="Alice", age=25, email="alice@example.com")
     25 
     26 # Save the instance to Redis as a JSON document

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/redis_om/model/model.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1676 
   1677     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
-> 1678         if not has_redis_json(self.db()):
   1679             log.error(
   1680                 "Your Redis instance does not have the RedisJson module "

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/redis_om/checks.py in has_redis_json(conn)
     15     if conn is None:
     16         conn = get_redis_connection()
---> 17     command_exists = check_for_command(conn, "json.set")
     18     return command_exists
     19 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/redis_om/checks.py in check_for_command(conn, cmd)
      7 @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
      8 def check_for_command(conn, cmd):
----> 9     cmd_info = conn.execute_command("command", "info", cmd)
     10     return None not in cmd_info
     11 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/redis/client.py in execute_command(self, *args, **options)
   1264         pool = self.connection_pool
   1265         command_name = args[0]
-> 1266         conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
   1267 
   1268         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/redis/connection.py in get_connection(self, command_name, *keys, **options)
   1459         try:
   1460             # ensure this connection is connected to Redis
-> 1461             connection.connect()
   1462             # connections that the pool provides should be ready to send
   1463             # a command. if not, the connection was either returned to the

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/redis/connection.py in connect(self)
    711             raise TimeoutError("Timeout connecting to server")
    712         except OSError as e:
--> 713             raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
    714 
    715         self._sock = sock

ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.
```

Notes:

1. My provided port on redis cloud is not 6379 and I don't understand why is the script trying to use localhost
2. My modules on the redis cloud are configured to Redis Stack
3. Using my connection credentials I'm able to read write and read data to / from a stream - so the credentials are correct
4. I see in the Redis documentation that it is possible to use JsonModel on a redis cloud

Script used:

```
!pip install redis
!pip install redis-om
import redis
import redis_om
from redis_om import JsonModel, Field


server_ip = "my correct redis cloud server_ip"
port =  "my correct redis cloud port"
password =  "my correct redis cloud password"

# Connect to the Redis instance
client = redis.Redis(host=server_ip, port=port, password=password)

# Define a custom model class using JsonModel
class Person(JsonModel):
    name: str = Field(index=True)
    age: int 
    email: str 

# Create an instance of the model class with some data
person = Person(name="Alice", age=25, email="alice@example.com")

# Save the instance to Redis as a JSON document
person.save()

# Print the ID and the JSON representation of the instance
print(person.id)
print(person.to_json())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a Redis client `client` with your server credentials, but not using that with the Redis OM models, so it's assuming that Redis is on `localhost:6379` and trying to reach it there.

Redis OM Python allows you to specify where Redis is using the `REDIS_OM_URL` environment variable, which expects a Redis URL format (https://github.com/redis/redis-om-python/blob/main/docs/connections.md)

So you'll need to set that.  Example value would be:

```
redis://default:<password>@<host>:<port>/
```

Replacing `<host>`, `<port>` and `<password>` with your Redis Cloud host, port and password values respectively.